# Parallax Scroll image behind Tablayout

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve a specific layout design for one of the Fragments that live inside Tablayout.

So, I have 3 different tabs inside tab layout which each of them has specific design.
One of these tabs contains an image view, a recycler view, and fixed to the bottom layout.

[image]

My desired behavior is that when the user scroll to the most recent chat message (like whatspp) the image will collapse under the tabs and when the user scrolls backward the image will appear again. in all that time the blue view in the picture (message input) should stay fixed to the bottom.

Honestly, I don't know where to start, most of the examples I saw are for coordinator layout in which the image view is changing the main app bar layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as a **header of recyclerView** and control its visibility with animation or something else.
all of these is possible with  [**ItemDecorator**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration)

Comment: thanks, I've ended up using CollapsingToolbarLayout